# How do I click the Span with Python Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here][1]I dont know how to select and click the red underlined. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEyAb.png
If I run the code the span is already open but I cant select a number. This is the Webiste which I try to automate https://shop.jaegermeister.de/account/index/sTarget/shotmachine
This is my Code so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time 


PATH = r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://shop.jaegermeister.de/account/index/sTarget/shotmachine")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("field-wrap__checker").click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("firstname")
elem.send_keys("First")
time.sleep(1)


elem = driver.find_element_by_id("lastname")
elem.send_keys("Second")
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-selection__arrow").click()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException  I tried multiple things already....

Comment: Ok, we will also need the html from the page around the element you are looking for.

Comment: If you inspect the link you can see it. I dont know how to paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the element by its XPATH, which is by my own experience the most reliable. To do this, right click on the element in the DevTools, go to "copy and select" and click on "copy XPATH".

Also, it would help if you'd use `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable())` before using `driver.find_element_by_class_name`.

This of course requires the following imports:

`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`

`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: ```element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "select2-selection__arrow")))

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-selection__arrow").click()
time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='jae-registration-form']/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/span/span[1]/span[@select2-selection select2-selection--single='select2-register_personal_birthdate-result-ag88-3'")``` I have a webdriverwait timeout. Idk what I did wrong